# UNION Mysql queries does not work

Tags: php, mysql, union

I have a ticket made by **user 1** with two replies made by **user 2** and **user 5**. 
Logged as **user 4**, this query should return *1,2,5* - but it only returns *5 and 2*

```
SELECT DISTINCT `modid`
   FROM `comments`
   WHERE `tickets_id`='193' AND `modid`!='4'
UNION
SELECT `author` FROM `tickets`WHERE `ticketid`='193';
```

do you have any idea of why it does this?

Comment: Edit your question with sample data and desired results . . . or set up a SQL Fiddle.

Comment: did you run the two child queries separately and verify that they are returning 1/2/5?

Comment: @GordonLinoff it should return 1,2,5 but it returns 2,5 (not the result of the second query)

Comment: @MarcB I haven't thought about that D: - and thanks to you I found my error !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following query with join.I don't know exact db structure but by your query I think best you can do is following

```
SELECT DISTINCT modid
   FROM tickets Ticket
   INNER JOIN comments Comment ON(Ticket.ticketid=Comment.tickets_id)
   WHERE Comment.tickets_id='193' AND Comment.modid!='4'
```